# Ruby on Rails: Retrieve css element and check value

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think this is a pretty straight forward question so I'll get to it:

subject.rb

```
def current_step
    @current_step || steps.first
   end

   def steps
      if @title = 'Baseline'
       %w[sfmfa phq whoqol_bref positive_negative mses_self pam spsir change_questionnaire prosthesis cognitive comorbidity pain mspss audit ]
      elsif @title = 'Treatment Completion'
         %w[smfa phq whoqol_bref positive_negative pam spsir ssscq prosthesis pain complications mspss audit ptcs accessing_resources satisfaction ]
      else
         redirect_to @subjects_path 
         flash[:notice] = "Did not find title"
      end

   end
```

I'm trying to check the value of the Title element on my tc.html.erb webpage (this should return 'Treatment Completion'). At the moment the check isn't working, and I end up with the steps defined under 'Baseline' every time.

I have steps for a paginated form, and it all works for the Baseline page, so now I'm trying to pass a different set of elements as the steps definition for a different page.

I think I'm using the wrong accessor (@title). This ruby I'm using to provide the Title is:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Baseline') %>
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to determine the state of the view in the model. You should let the view handle the view logic, and if you want to store state, i.e. the point to which a user has progressed through the steps, you can use a column in your DB to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are a couple of things that are wrong. The first thing is that you're trying to use `redirect_to` in a model. This should be used in a controller. Second, `@subjects_path` is not an instance variable, it's a url helper, so that should not have an `@` sign before it. Third, you're assigning, not comparing the `if` statement (using `=` and not `==`).

So, to answer the original question, you could fix your original problem by:

```
def steps
  if @title == 'Baseline'
    %w[sfmfa phq whoqol_bref positive_negative mses_self pam spsir change_questionnaire prosthesis cognitive comorbidity pain mspss audit]
  elsif @title == 'Treatment Completion'
    %w[smfa phq whoqol_bref positive_negative pam spsir ssscq prosthesis pain complications mspss audit ptcs accessing_resources satisfaction]
  else
    redirect_to @subjects_path 
    flash[:notice] = "Did not find title"
  end
end
```

Note that that only fixes the third error.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that was the issue. As for everything in my else block, I just removed it. It was really just a place holder, but thank you for the insight.

Comment: So once I made those changes, I get his new error: undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass. I'm not sure where it came from, because without the if statement, a single example for baseline works with no error. Any ideas? Or should I make a separate thread? Thanks again. EDIT. Nevermind, it just turns out my logic isn't working.

Comment: Likely your `@title` variable is not one of 'Baseline' or 'Treatment Completion' and therefore `steps` is returning `nil`. You should put in an `else` that returns `[]` or something similar.